# Como autollenar un input con datos precargados dependiendo del valor de un dropdown y un valor numerico en otro input?

Tags: php, javascript, entrada, dropdownlist

Es la primera vez que realizare una pregunta que probablemente vaya a estar mal redactada asi que me disculpo por adelantado.

He trado de realizar lo solicitado en la pregunta desde hace 2 días y no he conseguido lograrlo, tampoco he encontrado algún tipo de respuesta por ningún lado.

Trate de aplicar la lógica que se utiliza en C# ya que es el idioma que mejor manejo. En cuanto a PHP y Javascript soy nuevo y probablemente este haciendo algo mal. Les Agradeceria su ayuda. `

```
var dropdown2 = document.getElementById("AlcanceProyecto");
     var monto = document.getElementById("MontoPresupuestado");
     var prueba;

    if( dropdown2.value=='4' && monto >=150000 && <=2000000)
    {
      prueba = "Licitación Concurso Público Nacional";
    }

    document.getElementById("Prueba") = prueba;

    }
```

```html
<div class="input-field col s12 m10 l10">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">attach_money</i>
                <input  id="MontoPresupuestado" name="MontoPresupuestado" type="number" class="validate" required title="Del Monto Presupuestado se Define Automaticamente la Modalidad/Metodología del Proceso">
                <label for="DescripcionAdquisicion">Monto Presupuestado US$</label>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12 m10 l10" id="destinoBCIE"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12 m10 l10">

              <select class="browser-default" id="AlcanceProyecto" name="AlcanceProyecto">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione el Alcance del Proyecto</option>
                <option value="1">Licitación Público Internacional</option>
                <option value="2">Licitación Público Nacional</option>
                <option value="3">Concurso Público Internacional</option>
                <option value="4">Concurso Público Nacional</option>
                <option value="5">Aplicación de Legislación Nacional</option>
                <option value="6">Comparación de Precios o Calificaciones</option>

              </select>
            </div>
            </div>
            
              <div class="input-field col s12 m10 l10">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">attach_money</i>
                <input  id="Prueba" name="Prueba" type="text" class="validate" required title="Del Monto Presupuestado se Define Automaticamente la Modalidad/Metodología del Proceso">
                <label for="Prueba">Alcance</label>
            </div>
```

`

Por ahora todo seria mediante datos precargados sin usar una base de datos y tanto el input como el dropdown los manejo con un ID para realizar la condicion en el js pero aun asi no logre hacerlo funcionar.

Comment: Favor de agregar el código que estas ejecutando para apoyarte de forma más exacta y Bienvenido!

Comment: Te pido me disculpes no haberlo agregado ya que es la primera vez que realizo una pregunta y no me queda claro el metodo para que el HTML y el JS sean visibles de manera correcta y muchas gracias por la bienvenida.

Comment: Logre agregar fragmento del codigo tal vez es un poco mas entendible ahora, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo simple con **Javascript**. Como sugerencia trata de que los valores que uses para los **options** sean siglas ya que si son números no se entienden a que opción seleccionado se hace la validación.

```html
<div class="input-field col s12 m10 l10">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">attach_money</i>
                <input  id="MontoPresupuestado" name="MontoPresupuestado" type="number" class="validate" required title="Del Monto Presupuestado se Define Automaticamente la Modalidad/Metodología del Proceso" onchange="LoadValues()">
                <label for="DescripcionAdquisicion">Monto Presupuestado US$</label>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12 m10 l10" id="destinoBCIE"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12 m10 l10">

              <select class="browser-default" id="AlcanceProyecto" name="AlcanceProyecto" onchange="LoadValues()" >
                <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione el Alcance del Proyecto</option>
                <option value="1">Licitación Público Internacional</option>
                <option value="2">Licitación Público Nacional</option>
                <option value="3">Concurso Público Internacional</option>
                <option value="4">Concurso Público Nacional</option>
                <option value="5">Aplicación de Legislación Nacional</option>
                <option value="6">Comparación de Precios o Calificaciones</option>

              </select>
            </div>
            </div>
            
              <div class="input-field col s12 m10 l10">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">attach_money</i>
                <input  id="Prueba" name="Prueba" type="text" class="validate" required title="Del Monto Presupuestado se Define Automaticamente la Modalidad/Metodología del Proceso">
                <label for="Prueba">Alcance</label>
            </div>
<script>

     //funcion que se ejeucta cuando seleccionas un valor cualquiera del select o cambias el monto ingresado
    function LoadValues(){ 
        
      //obtienes el valor de tu monto y el alcance
      var monto = document.getElementById("MontoPresupuestado").value; 
      var alcance = document.getElementById("AlcanceProyecto").value; 
      var msg ="";
      
      //primero validamos si el monto es un numero
      if(monto == "" || isNaN(monto) ){ //si es true quiere decir que no es un numero
        document.getElementById("Prueba").value ="";
        return;
      }
      
      
      // aplicamos un switch para hacer las validaciones segun sea el caso
      switch(alcance){
      case "1":
          if(monto > 500) //validacion si el monto es mayor a 500
            msg = "Si cumple";
          else
            msg = "No cumple";

          break;     
      // aqui agrega un case por cada condicion que necesites

      }
      //finalmente setea el mensaje que debe aparecer
      document.getElementById("Prueba").value = msg;

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta @berckyn, seria algo asi. Creo debi explicar un poco mejor los campos. En el monto presupuestado ira una cantidad y en el dropdwon pues se seleccionara algo de la lista obviamente. En Alcance lo que se mostrara sera algun texto dependiendo del monto ingresado y de la opcion seleccionado. Por Ejemplo si ingresa 500 en el monto y selecciona licitacion publica nacional que en alcance aparezca "Si cumple" por decir algo. Creo que dentro del for que tu usaste deberia realizar las condiciones mediante if y else pero no se si de esa manera funcionaria. De nuevo gracias.

Comment: Lo cual ya había intentado mediante ese tipo de condiciones pero no funciono, es mas el servidor ya no estaba cargando el javascript y trabajaba a puro html.

Comment: Actualizo mi respuesta según el ejemplo que me brindas.

Comment: ok, te lo agradezco.

Comment: hermano mil gracias, es justo lo que necesitaba